How to understand symbolism in literature (The Romance of the Rose)?
I'm currently reading The Romance of the Rose by Guillaume de Lorris & Jean de Meun, I've just finished Guillaume de Lorris' part and now I'm examining some paper on meaning of the crystals in Deduit's garden which I found online. It states that a lot of critics think that crystals symbolises the eyes, and it mentioned in the paper that most of them support their judgement mostly by the fact there're two of the crystals.
It seems so... naive and simple for me, like it's not a proper argument, so how do I distinguish simple versions of meaning of things from nonsensical ones?
It is also mentioned in the paper that one of the critics bases his interpretation of the crystals on some earlier medieval poem in which eyes where described as a mirror. I wonder what I need to do to understand references like that in literature? I have some basic knowledge of world history, but it seems like it's not enough, and if I try to dig into history of the literature, it feels like I enter endless rabbit hole.
Apart from The Romance of the Rose, I would like to know how to distinguish (parts of) literary texts that support a symbolic interpretation from parts / texts that don't, because I tend to pay too much attention to every detail in the piece of literature I'm reading and I'm not always sure if I'm making things up or actually find some hidden meanings.

This question is very broad. Generally, one studies literature by epoch and type. Your choice is difficult as the poem was originally in Medieval French so even native French speakers need help. It is an allegory with a rose (love?) as a main symbol. You might want to start by getting a good literary dictionary from Routledge, Cambridge or Oxford University Press and reading about symbolism to start. Then, Medieval French poetry (via google). The only way to distinguish meanings about things like mirrors, roses or eyes is to read and also check the literature on these subjects.

Judging by the number of questions about symbolism that have already been asked on this site, your question is not unusual. Literature requires reading between the lines and this type of reading requires openness to symbolic meanings. Thomas C. Foster's book How to Read Literature Like a Professor is to a large extent about recognising symbols, allusions and connections in literary texts.
Literary texts can use other texts (literary or otherwise) as a source of plots, characters, allusions, metaphors, symbols, etcetera. Frequently used sources include myth (in a very broad sense, not just Greek and Germanic mythology), the Bible (at least in cultures influenced by Christianity) and literary giants such as Shakespeare. Modern readers cannot be expected to recognise all the allusions and sources. If you are not a professor of medieval literature, you are not very likely to recognise allusions in Le Roman de la Rose to other medieval texts. You can relax about it; it's fine. (That is also Thomas C. Foster's message.)
One of the problems with symbols is that many readers assume they can mean one thing only and that there is therefore only one correct interpretation [1]. Unless you are dealing with allegory, this is usually not the case. Some symbols have a limited range of meanings. For example, a white flag often means surrender or a request for parley. In literary texts, it is perfectly normal that different readers come up with different interpretations for the same symbol. That is perfectly fine. The goal of literary criticism is not to reach consensus on a literary text but to discover (more) meanings.
At the end of How to Read Literature Like a Professor, Thomas Foster includes a chapter titled "Who's in Charge Here?" The chapter addresses a question many students and readers ask, namely how they can know their interpretation is correct. Foster encourages readers to trust their own judgement. As you as you read carefully, neither ignoring parts of the text nor inserting words or statements that aren't there, you can make a convincing case for your interpretation. He ends the chapter with the following words (page 301):

Don't cede control of your opinions to critics, teachers, famous writers, or know-it-all professors. Listen to them, but read confidently and assertively, and don't be ashamed or apologetic about your reading. You and I both know you're capable and intelligent, so don't let anyone tell you otherwise. Trust the text and your instincts, you'll rarely go far wrong.

References

Foster, Thomas C.: How to Read Literature Like a Professor. Revised edition. New York: Harper Perennial, 2014.

[1] Another problem with symbols is that many readers only expect objects and images to serve as symbols and neglect the potential symbolic meanings of events and actions. (Foster: How to Read Literature Like a Professor, page 112)
See also the somewhat related question How do people learn to analyze literature?
